# Fiddler not working for ASP.Net Core

Tags: .net-core

I have been using fiddler in normal .net web applications to view 3rd party web service calls.  I have now updated my application to .net core and find fiddler no longer captures traffic to the 3rd party services.  Am I missing something?

Have check HTTPS Decrypt and all all related settings seem fine as if I use the normal .net framework all works well.

Comment: Fiddler captures all network traffic, regardless of the application which generates it (unless you have set up some kind of filter). Have you added any kind of filters? I know it's a stupid question, but are the client or server on the machine that you are running Fiddler on?

Comment: No Filters from what i can see filter section is disabled.  Again like i mentioned the fact that opening the .net framework app works is interesting.  This is why I am wondering if it might be to do with .net core using Kestral and having now web.config file.